# Computer Virus Spread Simulation - How to make each trial have random outputs?

Tags: java, probability, montecarlo

This code is used to simulate the virus spread in the network of 20 computers with the probability of 0.1 ~ 10%. It initially starts with only 1 computer being infected and each day has a chance that it spreads to other computers in the network. The output for each trial should be: time to remove the virus from the network, probability that each computer gets infected at least once, and the expected number of computers that get infected each trial. Logically each trial should have a random for each of the outputs listed. My problem is that each trial produces the same output, and I don't understand why it does that.

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class VirusSpreadSimulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numTrials = 5;
        int numComputers = 20;
        double pSpread = 0.1;
        int numInitialInfected = 1;
        int numToRemove = 5;

        int[] timesToRemoveVirus = new int[numTrials];
        double[] probAnyComputerInfected = new double[numTrials];
        double[] expectedInfectedComputers = new double[numTrials];

        for (int trial = 0; trial < numTrials; trial++) {
            Random random = new Random();  // Create a new Random instance for each trial
            int numInfected = numInitialInfected;
            int t = 1;

            while (numInfected > 0) {
                double[] randomNumbers = new double[numComputers - numInfected];
                for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
                    randomNumbers[i] = random.nextDouble();
                }

                numInfected = countInfections(randomNumbers, pSpread);

                int numToRemoveThisRound = Math.min(numInfected, numToRemove);
                for (int i = 0; i < numToRemoveThisRound; i++) {
                    // Simulate cleaning infected computers
                    int randomInfectedComputer = random.nextInt(numComputers);
                    // Set the corresponding infected computer to uninfected
                    numInfected--;
                }
            }

            t++; // Increment time (day)

            // Record results for the current trial
            timesToRemoveVirus[trial] = t;
            probAnyComputerInfected[trial] = calculateProbAnyComputerInfected(numComputers, pSpread);
            expectedInfectedComputers[trial] = calculateExpectedInfectedComputers(numComputers, pSpread);

            // Printing out each individual trial
            System.out.println("Individual Trials: ");

            System.out.println("Time to remove virus: " + timesToRemoveVirus[trial] + " days");
            System.out.println("Probability that each computer gets infected at least once: "
                    + probAnyComputerInfected[trial]);
            System.out.println("Expected number of computers infected: " + expectedInfectedComputers[trial]);
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Calculating the average of all trials
        double averageTimeToRemoveVirus = Arrays.stream(timesToRemoveVirus).average().orElse(0);
        double averageProbAnyComputerInfected = Arrays.stream(probAnyComputerInfected).average().orElse(0);
        double averageExpectedInfectedComputers = Arrays.stream(expectedInfectedComputers).average().orElse(0);

        // Printing out the averages
        System.out.println("Number of trials: " + numTrials);
        System.out.println("Average time to remove virus: " + averageTimeToRemoveVirus + " days");
        System.out.println("Average probability that each computer gets infected at least once: "
                + averageProbAnyComputerInfected);
        System.out.println("Average expected number of computers infected: " + averageExpectedInfectedComputers);
    }

    // Function that stores an array of infected computer for each trial
    private static int countInfections(double[] randomNumbers, double pSpread) {
        return (int) Arrays.stream(randomNumbers).filter(num -> num < pSpread).count();
    }

    // Function that calculates the each computer get infected at least once
    private static double calculateProbAnyComputerInfected(int numComputers, double pSpread) {
        double probNoInfections = Math.pow(1 - pSpread, numComputers);
        return 1 - probNoInfections;
    }

    // Function that calculates the number computers that get infected with each trial
    private static double calculateExpectedInfectedComputers(int numComputers, double pSpread) {
        return numComputers * (1 - Math.pow(1 - pSpread, numComputers));
    }
}
```

I tried using the random instance and putting inside the for loop that counts the trials hoping that it would reset the values with each trial. As I said previously, each trial has the same outputs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A few issues I see: (1) `t` is always a value of 2 for each trial (set to 1 and then incremented once) (2) `probAnyComputerInfected` and `expectedInfectedComputers` for each trial are computed with always the same inputs (20, 0.1).  Those are the three trial outputs always the same.  Also `randomInfectedComputer` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

*How to make each trial have random outputs?*

All you need to use is a pseudo random number generator. It already exists in Java: [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html)

Any instance of Random can generate integers, floats or double values. It depends what you ask it to do.

With your probability between 0.1 and 10 it could mean you go with integer values in the range of 1 to 100 and divide by 10. So you could run

```
Random generator = new Random();
float percentage = generator.nextInt(100) / 10.0f;
```

You could as well use nextFloag() which will produce a value between 0 and 1. This you need to map into your range:

```
Random generator = new Random();
float percentage = generator.nextFloat() * (10f-0.1f) + 0.1f;
```

If I misinterpreted your ranges just adapt the forumuas accordingly. What you need to be aware of is that the generated numbers are pseudo random. While they look random, the sequence they come in can be repeated. If you want to see this in action, initialize your generator with a seed:

```
Random generator = new Random(1234);
```

After that you should be able to repeatedly get the same values when calling nextInt() or nextFloat(). Such predictability is good for software testing/debugging but bad for encryption. In such cases initialize your random number generator like this:

```
Random generator = new SecureRandom();
```

See also [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Now let's get a closer look at your code. It seems you are running a loop, and inside the loop you are initializing your random number generator and retrieving one value. Per definition these may be the same. Move the line

```
Random random = new Random();
```

so it is before the loop and gets executed once only. With only one random number generator, this instance will deliver mutliple values and thus can start to distribute them over the possible range.